# Fiddler shows cookies in response but not seeing any cookies returned in HttpClient Cookie container

Tags: .net, cookies, httpclient, .net-6.0

c# .Net Core 6.0:

I'm using HTTPClient to post a JSON request and receiving a valid JSON response.  Using Fiddler I can see that the response contains 2 cookies.  But I'm not receiving these cookies in my cookie container.  Example code is as follows:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
handler.UseCookies = true;
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myUriBase);

StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postDict), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(loginUri.ToString(),content);
responseCookies1 = cookies.GetAllCookies();

string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`
```

In this case the stringResponse is OK and contains the data that I'm after, but the cookie count is 0, even though I can see the cookies in the response using Fiddler

Any ideas?

I.e. Fiddler shows:

Response sent 330 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: key=biLNdnxXkBtro0U01SQB4Yj9B%2FjXrh89m66DNj0Zhppbnsvvx%2Fa8NXPGDFw7t4nUcUHYXSuycrexsJts9D0lBCbGCcE%2Fdvpl6KXJOZfWNZa6D6XrJbbw4KeKDvU60mYvzmQK50YEy2O4X1FD9ARiwFZe5lHt1G61hup4NKWdXmqSibioz8ndDIQdJ7gI9ebKKQg3czoXDGHY25dvxWqKbe%2F6OOCdc6w8%2FxVP0XOgTpo%3D%3AOQb20qzZ40KLqvY7sC5VUg%3D%3D; path=/; expires=Sun, 10-Dec-2023 12:26:10 UTC

Response sent 117 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: appid=f6921e09e19ee6d1c89d954e9f288ab0b0c5d080c1e39fc08d073c21adc556e0; path=/; expires=Sun, 10-Dec-2023 12:26:10 UTC

Comment: _Side note_ Use [Httpclientfactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to create your `HttpClient` objects, also  use [using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187267/7450780) whenever making the http request and parsing the response.